# How to insert placeholder text in text_area_tag in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, textarea, placeholder

I'm using the following code to generate a `textarea` tag:

```
<%= text_area_tag :comment, '', autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Your Comment" %>
```

When rendered, it produces the following HTML:

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Comment"></textarea>
```

I know that if there is some text between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`, the  `placeholder` won't show up, but in my case, there is nothing in-between, as it is clear from rendered HTML. So how can I put a `placeholder`  text for `textarea`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The html seems to be valid to me.

```html
<textarea name="comment" autocomplete="off" class="test" id="moretest" data-value="moretest" placeholder="snowman or iceman?"></textarea>
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if I write `placeholder` just after the opening of `textarea`  or write at the very end?

Comment: there should be no difference.

Comment: So all I'm doing is putting `placeholder` at the end, and it isn't working.

Comment: nono what im saying is the HTML is correct. There should be a placeholder in your textarea if thats the output html.

Comment: It depends on the browser, the placeholder tag only work with HTML5 or more.

Comment: I'm using `Chrome 39.0.2171.99 (64-bit)`