# rails text_area placeholder not displayed

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, textarea

In my rails app I have a form where I use a text_area input.
Unfortunately my placeholder is not being displayed. When i change text_area to text_field, it does work. I found these two threads but they did not solve it for me:

1. [How to insert placeholder text in text_area_tag in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766232/how-to-insert-placeholder-text-in-text-area-tag-in-rails)
2. [Textarea Placeholder is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784016/textarea-placeholder-is-not-working)

Here is my code:

```
= f.text_area :description, placeholder: 'text'
```

Comment: How looks like the rendered html on your browser?

Comment: <textarea placeholder="Description" class="form-control" name="checkout_element[description]" id="checkout_element_description"></textarea>

Comment: I just [cut and paste your comment in codepen](https://codepen.io/alex3o0/pen/GRjQBqJ) and it did it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and realized my bug was in a different file called "formbuilder" which modified this textarea.